# Descripcion de una imagen en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Buenas,

Estoy intentando a través de un template tag de WP obtener la descripción de una imagen en concreto. He probado con the_title() y solo me saca el titulo.

¿Cómo se puede obtener el caption (descripción) de una imagen que tengo en la biblioteca?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener los diferentes elementos de la imagen de este modo:

```
function wp_get_attachment( $attachment_id ) {

    $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );
    return array(
        'alt' => get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ),
        'caption' => $attachment->post_excerpt,
        'description' => $attachment->post_content,
        'href' => get_permalink( $attachment->ID ),
        'src' => $attachment->guid,
        'title' => $attachment->post_title
    );
}
```

Fuente: [Wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/functions-to-get-an-attachments-caption-title-alt-description#post-22155)

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te ha servido/funcionado, ten en cuenta lo que se dice en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ( $images = get_posts(array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'title',
        'category_name' => 'category',
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    ))) :
    ?>
 
    
    <div class="" >
        
    <?php 
        foreach( $images as $image ) {
            $attachmenturl_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $image->ID );
            $attachmenturl = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
            $attachmentimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'full' );
            $imageDescription = apply_filters( 'the_description' , $image->post_content );
            $imageTitle = apply_filters( 'the_title' , $image->post_title );
           
            $i++;
            if (!empty($imageTitle)){
                ?>
   <!-- puedes ver que aca se muestra la imagen -->
            <img src=<?php echo $attachmentimage[0] ?> />
<!-- puedes ver que aca se muestra el titulo -->
            <?php echo $imageTitle; ?> 

     /><span class='text-center'> <?php echo $imageTitle; ?></span>
                
            
     <?php
        } 
    }
    ?> 
    
    </div>
```